# Trying to vertically split the header of a page into three areas but the right is appearing under the middle incorrectly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a header that is split three ways (a logo to the left, something in the middle, and something else to the right). The width of the header is 100%.

The issue I am having is that the right part only appears lower (under the info in the middle div). Not sure how to simply display the right part to the right in that case. I might not be explaining this very well, let me know if I can clear this up further.

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        logo
    </div>
    <div id="header-middle">

    </div>
    <div id="header-right">

    </div>
</div>
```

with the css:

```
#header {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    height: 55px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    overflow: auto;
}

#logo {
    font-size: 24pt;
    color: #08a3d9;
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
}

#header-middle {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#header-right {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your CSS is fine. Just move #header-middle last in your HTML.  Then what is float: right will go right, float: left will go left, and the middle content will fill upwards and occupy the unclaimed middle space.  What is happening the way you have it, is the unfloated element is pushing the floated element after it.

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
        logo
    </div>
    <div id="header-right">

    </div>
    <div id="header-middle">

    </div>
</div>
```

If changing the HTML order is not an option, then just assign widths to everything, and float all the items left.

Comment: Awesome, will accept the answer in a minute (it is not allowing me to accept the answer yet :))

Comment: Nice answer, that was very simple.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution for your consideration:

In the code below, I've removed all floats and used relative sizing to allow your design to better handle narrow ...

[image]

... and wide ...

[image]

... screen widths more responsively.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <style>
        #header {
            padding: 25px 10px;
            height: 55px;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
            overflow: no-content;
            min-width: 400px;
        }

        div#header div {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 1% 0;
            margin: 0 2%;
            text-align: center;
            border: 4px dashed; /* Useful for positioning */
            font-size: 2em;
        }

        #logo {
            color: #08a3d9;
            width: 20%;
            border-color: red; 
        }

        #header-middle {
            width: 40%;
            border-color: green; 
        }

        #header-right {
            width: 20%;
            border-color: blue; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo">
            logo
        </div>
        <div id="header-middle">
            middle
        </div>
        <div id="header-right">
            end
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd also recommend using something like [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) or [Columnal](http://www.columnal.com/) that provide a decent responsive grid system so that your site works beautifully on both desktop & mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I made another jsFiddle for you.

**updated** http://jsfiddle.net/zGfh7/

My answer is much more complicated than magi's, but it also works.

I added `float: left` to the middle header.

Also, I changed the widths of all the headers to 33%, and removed all margin-left and paddings, etc, to make things more clean. You can keep or change the 33% widths to your preference, but making sure that all the widths add up to 100% ensures that the header is nicely filled.

I've also added background-colors so you can see that things align nicely.

Comment: You need to save your js fiddle to get a proper link.